# FizzBuzz with more parameters in Swift

Tags: swift, fizzbuzz

Here's my approach to an extensible version of the FizzBuzz challenge in Swift (so one can add more numbers to be checked against other than just `3` and `5`).

I initially tried using dictionaries but since they don't necessarily preserve the order of elements it could lead to `BuzzFizz` return values.

I personally think that, while the program does work as expected, it isn't clear how it works. I mean, it's not as readable as I'd like it to be for doing such a simple task.

How can I improve it?

```
func fizzBuzz (n: Int, responsesByMultiples: [(Int, String)] = [(3, "Fizz"), (5, "Buzz")]) -> String {
    var result: String = ""

    for key in responsesByMultiples {
        let (multiple, response) = key,
            isMultiple: Bool = (n % multiple) == 0

        if isMultiple {
            result += response
        }
    }
    return result == "" ? String(n) : result
}
for i in 1...100 {
    print(fizzBuzz(n: i))
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Bright side

Your code gives the correct output and delivers on the premise of extensibility.

## Suggestions

Here are some suggestions:

1. The name `key` is a name that doesn't tell a lot about the nature of the tuple. If you feel that it is appropriate, that would conflict with `responsesByMultiples`. Then It would have made more sense for the latter to be named `keys`. Personally, I'd prefer to call `responses` or `rules`.
2. These *rules* expressed by a tuple without labels is a little bit confusing. Better use a struct, or just add labels.
3. You can easily decompose a tuple this way:

   ```
   for (multiple, response) in responsesByMultiples {
       ...
   }
   ```
4. Calling the first element `multiple` is a little bit too optimistic (or pessimistic depending on the way you to see things), it presumes that there is a high probability that `n` is actually a multiple of `multiple`. It would make more sense to me to name the first element of the tuples `dividsor`.
5. `n` is a bit too generic, use `dividend` instead.
6. You don't have to specify the type in `isMultiple: Bool`, type inference can do the job for you. Generally speaking, specifying the type can help in reducing the compile times, but in this case, it wouldn't make a difference.
7. Instead of using `(n % multiple) == 0`, there is a nice [syntax](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0225-binaryinteger-iseven-isodd-ismultiple.md) in Swift 5 :

   ```
   n.isMultiple(of: multiple)
   ```

   (this syntax exacerbates the problem mentioned in 4.)
8. To check that a String is empty, it is more efficient to check the `.isEmpty` property. [Here](https://tio.run/##tY/PSgQxDMbv8xRh8NCClgoeZNnByyp68rAPsNRpZzfQP0ObUZZlX93aVlnwLAYSQki@75f0gRPdZXRziARPYfFaEQafrSFQMaojDMCkEOvbnZSyJhdOzXCCHaDv4Cc2YXmzRkTldXAM/QraDYd1ae7hAfoeVrCliH7P@mdjbehFOizTZI1mnDehc9fpAKfWV/9EqkANsFFkGL@Mo0mLrfPGJya0ZGIBupIwDNXofFk1Xv@@b2UuFMS@ZcRYfqbruikInXnxRexd2S360bBGUOj@TCYwPbqZjv/BlvPnOFm1T/nm9Qs) is a benchmark that confirms it:

   ```
   import Foundation

   let array = (0..<1_000_000).map { _ in
       Double.random(in: 0..<1) < 0.8 ? "" : String("Hello".shuffled())
   }

   do {
       let start = Date()
       let result = array.filter { $0 == "" }
       let end = Date()

       print(result.count, end.timeIntervalSince(start))
   }

   do {
       let start = Date()
       let result = array.filter { $0.isEmpty }
       let end = Date()

       print(result.count, end.timeIntervalSince(start))
   }
   ```

   The execution times are respectively `44ms` and `34ms`.

## Putting it all together ❤️

Here a version of your code that takes the previous points into account :

```
func fizzBuzz (
    number dividend: Int,
    rules: [(Int, String)] = [(3, "Fizz"), (5, "Buzz")]
    ) -> String {

    var result: String = ""

    for (divider, response) in rules
        where dividend.isMultiple(of: divider) {
        result += response
    }

    return result.isEmpty ? String(dividend) : result
}
```

## Further reading

You can find many implementations of this classic question on Code Review. [Here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/91663/49921) is a quite informative one.

Comment: Damn that is a very well formatted answer! I agree with every point on the list, except maybe #6 because I personally like using explicit typing. Thanks!